# Using touchpad to make desktop icons bigger

Tags: windows-10

I try to drag a desktop icon to the recycle bin using the touchpad of my laptop.

I am *not* holding down the ctrl key on the keyboard.

In some situations, this does not work.
Instead, the icons on the desktop are made bigger or smaller.

This is a cool feature, but I can not reproduce it all the time, and since I'm using the touchpad, it is not really clear to me what I am doing when this happens.

What is this function called, and how can I reproduce this?

Comment: Are you sure some other part of your hand isn't touching the pad?  On all of my machines, this happens if I pinch or spread two touch-points on the pad.  I would suggest that you are touching more than one point or there is a problem with your pad.

Comment: Also try the. Control key and then  touch pad to see. I use this function to change icon size.